# Linear Independence in polynomial space.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

[image]

Here $P_m(F)$ is the space of polynomials of degree at most m.

My reasoning thus far has been to write each $p_j$ as 
$$p_j=(x-2)\times q_j$$
where $q_j$ is a polynomial of degree at most $(m-1)$.

If we consider the expression 
$$a_0p_0 + a_1p_1 +\cdots+ a_mp_m = (x-2)\times [a_0q_0 + a_1q_1 +\cdots+ a_mq_m] = 0$$
then at $x=2$ any collection of $a_j$ would satisfy the expression. Hence the list $(p_0,p_1,\cdots,p_m)$ is not linearly independent in $P_m(F)$.

I'm not sure about this reasoning though. In my understanding, shouldn't the $a_j$ be independent of the $x$, i.e. the expression $a_0p_0 + a_1p_1 +\cdots+ a_mp_m$ equals zero because the coefficients of the ${x^j}$ cancel each other out, but not because $x=2$ makes it so?

Comment: You only  noticed that any set of $aj$s works `at x = 2 `, not for all x. It must be the same linear relation for all $x$.

Comment: I see. So it's really the case that the $a_js$ must be independent of the $x's$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Let $Z$ be the subspace of $\mathcal P_m$ which vanish at $x=2$. Using your notations, observe the linear mapping
\begin{align}
Z&\longrightarrow\mathcal P_{m-1}\\
p&\longmapsto q=\frac p{x-2}
\end{align}
is injective, hence the dimension of the image is equal to $\dim Z$. What is the dimension of $\mathcal P_{m-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the (surjective) linear map $f\colon P_m(\mathbf{F})\to\mathbf{F}$ defined by $p\mapsto p(2)$.

Then $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m$ are $m+1$ elements in the kernel of $f$, which has dimension $m$ by the rank-nullity theorem and the fact that $\dim P_m(\mathbf{F})=m+1$.

Comment: I just want to ascertain something: is it true that if $p_0, p_1,..., p_m$ are not linearly independent in the smaller space $ker(f)$, then it is not linearly independent in the bigger space $P_m(F)$?

Comment: @ensbana That's correct. Linear dependence or independence of a set of vectors does not depend on the subspace these vectors belong to (of course the subspace must contain them all).

Answer (score 1):

If $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m$ were linearly independent in $P_m(F)$, then they would form a basis of $P_m(F)$, which has dimension $m+1$.
But then every polynomial $p\in P_m(F)$ would be a linear combination of $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m$, and so $p(2)=0$. This clearly does not hold for all polynomials; it certainly does not hold for nonzero constant polynomials.